# Помідор чи томат?

Tags: вибір-слова

*Помідор* - 1. це однорічна рослина; 2.соковитий плід цієї рослини, а *томат* - паста з помідорів.

Чому при назві насіння певного сорту використовують обидві назви *Помідор Хуго* або *Томат Хуго*? В супермаркеті для назви плодів все частіше використовують слово *"томат"* (*Томати тепличні*).

Як правильно говорити: *помідор* чи *томат*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах (1970-і–1980-і) пише:

> [**ТОМА́Т**](http://sum.in.ua/s/tomat), *ч[оловічий рід]*.
>
> 1. *[закінчення у] род[овому відмінку]* а. Помідор. <…>

Таким чином слово *томат* наслідує всі значення слова *помідор*: і рослина, і плід.

<sub>Я було був подумав, що це одрук, що малося на увазі «томат = помідор 1», тобто лише перше значення слова *помідор*, тобто лише рослина — але ні, після перевірки в Google Книгах справді виявилося, що все правильно, *томат* використовують у обох значеннях.</sub>

Тобто **слово *помідор* теоретично завжди можна замінити на слово *томат***. (Практично все залежить від середовища, в якому Ви живете — якщо всі звикли називати це *помідором*, а Ви за столом скажете: «Передайте мені, будь ласка, томат» (або навпаки) — люди можуть здивуватися.)

Окрім того **слово *томат* має додаткове значення, якого не має слово *помідор***:

> 1. *[закінчення у] род[овому відмінку]* у. Соус, паста з помідорів.

Тобто слово *томат* не завжди можна замінити на слово *помідор*. *Томат* — гіперонім *помідора*. Зверніть увагу також на те, що у значенні «= помідор» і у значенні «паста/соус» слово *томат* має різні закінчення родового відмінку.

Comment: "помідорний сік" чомусь не набув поширення

Comment: @hutorny, [трішки вживається](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22помідорний+сік%22+OR+%22помідорного+соку%22+OR+%22помідорному+соку%22+OR+%22помідорним+соком%22) (зокрема в сучасних книжках). Але відповідь була про іменники. Якщо іменники якось співвідносяться, то це не означає, що утворені від них прикметники так само співвідносяться.

Answer (score 0):

Овочева культура - помідори (у множині), окремий плід - помідор (в однині).

Що каже академічний Словник української мови? (бо в попередній відповіді висмикнуто словникову статтю про помідор):

ПОМІДО́Р, а, чол.

1. Однорічна овочева рослина родини пасльонових з перев. червоними або жовтими їстівними плодами. Цей шкідник [стеблова нематода], крім картоплі, може розвиватись і на інших рослинах — помідорах, чорному пасльоні, хмелі, м'яті тощо (Наука і життя, 8, 1959, 36); Я в своїй вандальській заїлості не розбирав, чи нищу шкідливі ростини, будяки, кропиву, осет та лопухи, чи пожиточні — буряки, фасолю, помідори (Іван Франко, IV, 1950, 225).
2. Соковитий плід цієї рослини. У супермаркетах начйчастіше використовують термін "томат" через зросіщення, бо саме така назва культури переважає в російській мові, хоча раніше там також вирощували "помідори". Назва соусу чи пасти, утворена від "томатів" також залишилася з радянських часів.

Щодо "томатів":

ТОМА́Т, чол.

1. род. а. Помідор. Плоди томатів, що достигли при штучному освітленні, містять сухої речовини у два з лишком рази, вітаміну C в два рази, цукру в півтора рази більше порівняно з томатами, вирощеними у звичайних умовах (Хлібороб України, 11, 1968, 5).
2. род. у. Соус, паста з помідорів. Я відкрив бляшанку бичків у томаті, нарізав хліба; Марія вимостила з дощок стіл і заслала газетою (Анатолій Хорунжий, Ковила, 1960, 63).

Коли в росії почати вирощувати помідори, то там широко використовувалася саме ця назва, що прийшла з України де ця південна культура з'явилася раніше (сама назва є запозиченням з італійської - помо д'оро "золоте яблуко", бо ранше переважали жовті плоди). У радянські часи в російській мові перевагу надали терміну "томат" (запозичення з мов американських аборигенів "томатль"), а через політику заміни українських термінів росйіськими та тотальне зросіщення, томат вкорінився й на Украйні. Тоді ж з'явилися томатна паста й томатний сік. Наслідки зросійщення відчуваються в багатьох супермакетах, де цураються помідорів.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).